# How to enrich events using a very large database with azure stream analytics?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I'm in the process of analyzing Azure Stream Analytics to replace a stream processing solutions based on NiFi with some REST microservices.

One step is the enrichment of sensor data form a very large database of sensors (>120Gb).

Is it possible with Azure Stream Analytics? I tried with a very small subset of the data (60Mb) and couldn't even get it to run.

Job logs give me warnings of memory usage being too high. Tried scaling to 36 stream units to see if it was even possible, to no avail.

What strategies do I have to make it work?

If I deterministically (via a hash function) partition the input stream using N partitions by ID and then partition the database using the same hash function (to get id on stream and ID on database to the same partition) can I make this work? Do I need to create several separated stream analytics jobs do be able to do that?

I suppose I can use 5Gb chunks, but I could not get it to work with ADSL Gen2 datalake. Does it really only works with Azure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Stream Analytics supports reference datasets of [up to 5GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data#size-limitation). Please note that large reference datasets come with the downside of making jobs/nodes restarts very slow (up to 20 minutes for the ref data to be distributed; restarts that may be user initiated, for service updates, or various errors).

If you can downsize that 120Gb to 5Gb (scoping only the columns and rows you need, converting to types that are smaller in size), then you should be able to run that workload. Sadly we don't support partitioned reference data yet. This means that as of now, if you have to use ASA, and can't reduce those 120Gb, then you will have to deploy 1 distinct job for each subset of stream/reference data.

Now I'm surprised you couldn't get a 60Mb ref data to run, if you have details on what exactly went wrong, I'm happy to provide guidance.